# How to connect Azure toolkit for intelliJ/Eclipse to national cloud like Mooncake?

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, intellij-idea, azure-java-tools

I am using the Azure toolkit for intelliJ to deploy my Web App on azure. However, official sign in guidance do not cover national cloud like Mooncake (Azure for China). Any existing workaround on that?

So far, the sign in options in Azure toolkit for intelliJ/Eclipse all lead to:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/

While the authenticate page for Mooncake is at:
https://login.partner.microsoftonline.cn/

Comment: This is now documented at: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/wiki/FAQ#1-how-to-login-to-national-clouds

Answer (score 1):

Here is Azure offical Chinese document [link](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/articles/guidance/developerdifferences?toc=%2Fguides%2Fdeveloper%2Ftoc.json#%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E5%8C%BA-azure-%E8%B5%84%E6%BA%90%E7%AB%AF%E7%82%B9uri-%E4%BE%9B%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E4%BB%A3%E7%A0%81%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8) shown the cross-reference table of resource endpoint urls for China and Global. And according to the source code [`AuthenticationAuthority.java`](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/blob/79994cd679a092b6512972c7b8f2a836da52abda/Utils/azuretools-core/src/com/microsoft/azuretools/adauth/AuthenticationAuthority.java#L17) for Azure Toolkit for Java, the authentication endpoint for China environment should be `login.chinacloudapi.cn`.

Next, please refer to the GitHub issue [`\[IntelliJ and Eclipse\]Mooncake Sign in with Interactive not work on Mac`](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/issues/1232), to select different Azure environment like China Mooncake, you need to create a configuration file named `AadProvider.json` with the content below to enable the related authenticate page.

```
{
    "EnvironmentName": "CHINA"
}
```

On Windows, the `AadProvider.json` file is at the path as the figure below.

[image]